# commodity futures options data

Tags: options, futures, commodities, option-data

I am trying to get my hands on some historical commodity futures options data for about 35 commodity futures.
So far in my search the only way I can get the data seems to be through the Commodity Research Bureau.
I was wondering if anyone knows any other source readily available to academics such as through datastream or bloomberg, where I can get this data?
Alternatively, are there any other vendors who have historical commodity futures options data that I can access via an API for a reasonable fee?

Comment: CME Datamine may be a relatively inexpensive choice for endofday option on futures data  http://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/datamine-faq.html

Comment: I looked into the CME option and it was relatively expensive. $2000 for the full history of only gold futures options.

Comment: Sorry to hear that...

Comment: Unfortunately Bloomberg doesn't have any historical data for options on futures.  Did you find a source?

Comment: have you tried quandl ?